# Laravel global access with polymorphic relations

Tags: php, laravel, global-methods

In my application I have two columns `employable_id` && `employable_type` in almost every table, which are used for storing the information about the user who has created the record.

Something like this:

```
subscribers:                          products:
------------------------------------  ------------------------------------
id | employable_id | employable_type  id | employable_id | employable_type
------------------------------------  ------------------------------------
 1 |             1 | App\Company       1 |             1 | App\Company
 2 |             1 | App\Company       2 |             1 | App\Employee
 3 |             1 | App\Employee      3 |             3 | App\Employee
 4 |             1 | App\Employee      4 |             8 | App\Employee     and more...
```

Subscriber.php

```php
class Subscriber extends Model
{
    /**
     * Polymorphic relations
     */
    public function employable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I have created an `accessor` to combine polymorphic relationship's columns, which is working fine.

```php
class Subscriber extends Model
{
    /**
     * Polymorphic relations
     */
    public function employable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * Accessor
     */
    public function getAddedByAttribute()
    {
        return $this->employable->name . ' [ ' . $this->employable->designation . ' ]';
    }
}
```

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Polymorphic relations
     */
    public function employable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * Accessor
     */
    public function getAddedByAttribute()
    {
        return $this->employable->name . ' [ ' . $this->employable->designation . ' ]';
    }
}
```

I am trying to make the `getAddedByAttribute` method global instead of adding in every model class.

How can I do that..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a trait and use it in every model need this function

Comment: Thanks @MohammadAlama, It worked. Thanks again :)